# SharePoint Error: Distributed cache service is not running in this deployment

Tags: sharepoint-server, distributedcache

I installed SharePoint 2013 on windows server 2008 R2 SP1 in **standalone mode**.
When I ran configuration wizard, I encountered an Error (Failed to create sample data) and I fixed it with a solution mentioned [here](http://squidpip.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-preview-configuration/).
After that, I opened Central Administration and I saw the message: "The SharePoint Health Analyzer has detected some critical issues that require your attention. View these issues."

the issues are:

- More Cache hosts are running in this deployment than are registered
  with SharePoint. (warning)
- Distributed cache service is not enabled in this deployment. (error)
- This Distributed Cache host may cause cache reliability problems. (warning)

The warnings say the AppFabric must be Stopped, but the error solution says Distributed Cache Service must be started.

I do many searched in google, but I couldn't fix these problems and I really confused.
Is there anybody to help me?

Answer (score 3):

In your Case what i understand you Distributed cache is not properly configured. You need to repair it.

- From Central Admin > Manage Services on Server > Make Sure DC services is started
- Run the below mentioned powershell command to repair it.
- $instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService
  Name=AppFabricCachingService" $serviceInstance =
  Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($*.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName
  -and ($*.server.name) -eq $env:computername}

  $s.delete()

Now the below command to add the server back in the cluster.

```
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

to verify if it is working run below.

```
Use-CacheCluster

Get-CacheHost ( result should be like this if its up otherwise down or unknown)
```

> HostName : CachePort    Service Name     Service Status   Version
>
> --------------------   -----------        --------------   -------
>
> Name server:22233  AppFabricCachingService UP 3 [3,3] [1,3]

ComputerName: Name of the server where DC running

CachePort:  22233

- Now run the below command

  Get-CacheHostConfig

You will get the result like this:

```
HostName        : name of the Server
ClusterPort     : 22234
CachePort       : 22233
ArbitrationPort : 22235
ReplicationPort : 22236

Size            : 819 MB
ServiceName     : AppFabricCachingService
HighWatermark   : 99%
LowWatermark    : 90%
IsLeadHost      : True
******************************************************
```

Comment: DC in Central Admin > Manage Services on Server is not started and I cann't start it manually. I give the error message "Sorry, something went wrong, cacheHostInfo is null". I checked AppFabric in services.msc and it is started.

Comment: make sure the services under which AppFabric service is running should be in Local Admin group on server

Comment: Which services running under App Fabric Service? I went to the services->AppFabric->properties->dependencies and did not see any dependency services.

Comment: Sorry, I mean service account not services

Answer (score 1):

I have answered your issue here:

[New-SPConfigurationDatabase Failed in SharePoint workgroup installation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111243/new-spconfigurationdatabase-failed-in-sharepoint-workgroup-installation)

**solution**:

run this powershell script:

```
psconfig.exe -cmd Configdb Create SkipRegisterAsDistributedCacheHost
```

Comment: This solution is appropriate for configuration step. However, I tested it and it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Distributed Cache can be a headache, First check on what CU your App fabric is if anything below CU5 then you probably need to update (I think the latest is CU7). You can check that through the control panel.

For general troubleshooting use the script and the guidelines from here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/filipbosmans/archive/2015/09/07/how-to-check-for-issues-with-distributed-cache-and-the-script.aspx

Recently I had issue with the DistCache not starting and the solution was to export, make couple of changes and import it again (and do it again with the original settings) 
    - http://codebender.denniland.com/sharepoint-server-2013-issue-appfabric-distributed-cache-service-crashes/

Hope that helps