# New-SPConfigurationDatabase Failed in SharePoint workgroup installation

Tags: sharepoint-server, standalone, workgroup

I installed SharePoint 2013 on fresh windows server 2008 R2 SP1 in **standalone** mode. **SharePoint prerequisites installed automatically from net**.
After I configured SharePoint, My Distributed Cache Service was stopped and I cannot start it.

I searched in google and I found [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/Norgean/archive/2012/07/21/installing-sharepoint-2013-preview-on-a-standalone-workgroup-server.aspx) and other links that sayed If I want to install SharePoint in standalone mode in workgroup, I must run `New-SPConfigurationDatabase` command before running configuration wizard.

So I installed SharePoint again (I'am using VM), and when I run `New-SPConfigurationDatabase` I got error:

> `New-SPConfigurationDatabase` cannot connect to database master at SQL server at db name. The DB may not exist, or the current user does not have permission to connect.

I used of built-in administrator account in form `domain\account`.
How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

to re-enable using powershell "after install":

```
$InstanceName = "SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService";            
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.server.name) -eq $env:computername}            
$serviceInstance.Provision();
```

Comment: how do I access to SQL management studio?

Comment: I have not SSMS in my system, and I can not success to install it. Also, use the "psconfig.exe -cmd Configdb Create SkipRegisterAsDistributedCacheHost" command caused the distributed cache service will be stopped and not start anyway.

Comment: Dear @ali SharePoint , Should you ensure that the image is displayed properly ? I can't see it !

Comment: images are messed up for some reason. added the links below each one just incase

Comment: The uploaded images seems to be blank even on link click

Comment: updated, no image... just enable using powershell after you have installed sharepoint 2013 on the server.